# Surface Pro 3 Reboot after Shutdown

Tags: windows-8, shutdown, reboot

I have a Microsoft Surface Pro 3 tablet. For the past couple weeks I have been experiencing an issue where when I turn the surface off either by the physical hardware button or through the OS (Windows 8.1) it will automatically reboot once it has shut down.

I have looked into other sources and I have turned off the wake features for the keyboard cover, HID compliant keyboard, and HID compliant mouse within device manager.

I have also disabled the wake feature within the power settings. The issue is still persisting. I have also used the powercfg command to list other devices that are able to wake the device, I have not disabled anything other than the ones listed above. I have also run the command through powercfg in command prompt that lists what has last waked the device.

Commands:

```
powercfg -lastwake
powercfg -devicequery wake_from_any
```

Suspecting a power issue I have removed all devices such as the keyboard cover and USB devices, but the issue still persists.

Has anyone run into this issue before and found a solution?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: "I have also run the command through powercfg in command prompt that lists what has last waked the device. " And what was the result of that command?

Comment: Sorry about that, that was pretty important and I forgot to add it. 

It lists that no devices waked it. Which leads me to believe that it is not actually being woken up.

If it helps diagnose this a little bit in the event viewer it is listing it as a power on event and it occurs 9 seconds after the device is powered off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a guessing game, but since I installed Windows 10 it has since changed the settings of the network adapter twice, both times it removed the checkbox for requiring a magic packet (instead of any packet) to wake the computer under the Device Manager->NeworkCard->Properties->Power Management.

Another common issue is software. There was a bug in TeamViewer last Summer which would wake the PC from sleep. This has since been fixed, but similar bugs might be in other software. This is unlikely here because you say the system was actually shut down.

Last but not least there are hardware issues. Contact Microsoft, which might ask you to do a factory reset of the device - if the problem persists after that they will exchange it, unless it's past warranty.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I was thinking it was a hardware problem. I do find the information about the magic packet and the Teamviewer bug interesting.

It is unfortunately out of warranty so I figured I would see if anyone had experienced this as well.

Thanks again!

Comment: @DanielHayes Thanks for accepting. But I'd always wait a few hours before accepting any answer, since it discourages other posters from writing even better answers.